# Any free tool for Calculating Gasteiger-Hückel charges for ligands?

Tags: software, formal-charge

I want to know if there is any free open source tool available for Gasteiger-Hückel charge calculation? I know it is available on Sylbyl but is there any other(free) way to calculate these charges for small molecules?

I was actually trying this paper, if any one is interested,

[How to improve docking accuracy of AutoDock4.2: a case study using different electrostatic potentials.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23244516)

Hou X1, Du J, Zhang J, Du L, Fang H, Li M.X et al.

Comment: -1 means there are no software or it is not the right place to ask this question?

Comment: I think question is ok,

Answer (score 2):

The method is not [fully published](http://www.ccl.net/chemistry/resources/messages/2002/01/16.005-dir/) according to Gasteiger.

There is an [online server](http://www2.chemie.uni-erlangen.de/software/petra/) for PETRA run by the Gasteiger group, and in principal, it's available from [Molecular Networks](https://www.molecular-networks.com/products). I note that PETRA is no longer listed on the products page, but it's probably part of some other product now.

The open source [CDK](http://cdk.github.io/cdk/1.5/docs/api/org/openscience/cdk/charges/GasteigerPEPEPartialCharges.html) package has an implementation of the PEPE method, although I don't know if it has been validated against Gasteiger's code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, it means its not available for free as Molecular Networks is paid software. Never used CDK is it an api?

Comment: CDK is indeed an api (i.e., a toolkit in Java) but also has a web service [here](http://www.rguha.net/code/java/cdkws/cdkws.html)